# Is Errai using anything besides localStorage for offline persistence?

Tags: javascript, html, gwt, errai

For an upcoming project, we're evaluating GWT / Errai as the foundation.

As our application will be heavy in terms of data throughput and at the same time will often face offline use, we're worried about localStorage being a limiting factor - it varies between 2mb and 10mb depending on the browser.

The homepage of the Errai project does not mention any use of, for example, indexedDB or WebSQL to overcome the limit of localStorage.

Does anyone know if Errai is indeed relying on localStorage only (and hence is limited to max. 10mb offline storage)?